# /dev/shm size recommendation for postgres database in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

We have postgresql 11.7 database in docker container.

We had an issue `"pq: could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.XXX" to XXX bytes: No space left on device"`, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751565/pq-could-not-resize-shared-memory-segment-no-space-left-on-device).

Solution helped, we do not have an issue anymore. But which size should we set for shm_size for docker container with Postgres?

Is any recommendation? How can we calculate 'optimal size' for shm_size?

Comment: Depends on your `shared_buffers` setting. That depends on your requirements.

Comment: We also found that shm size depend on max_parallel_workers_per_gather parameter, not just only shared_buffers. We want to know more detailed recommensation...

We set shared_buffers to 1GB and shm size to 1.1GB but isse still persist. We set max_parallel_workers_per_gather from 2 to 1 and iisue was resolved.

For now we set shm_size to 2.2GB, shared_buffers 1 GB, max_parallel_workers_per_gather =2 and all fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things that use shared memory:

- The shared memory that is allocated at server start. This consists of several parts, but the lion's share is `shared_buffers`, the data cache.

  So you have to have more shared memory than that.
- Shared memory segments allocated by parallel query to communicate between parallel workers.

  Their size depends on the data transferred, and several of them can be allocated, so that is a resource that is harder to control.

On a memory-constrained system, I'd recommend that you disable parallel query. It makes queries faster, but uses more resources per query, so overall throughput doesn't improve. It is good if you want to throw a lot of resources on a single query.

To disable parallel query, set `max_parallel_workers` to 0.

Comment: Based on https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2448119 and observing the behavior of the PostgreSQL Docker image, I'm not convinced `shared_buffers` is allocated from shm. We're running with 1GB shared_buffers and shm-size of 256MB and it seems to be OK.

Comment: @lmsurprenant PostgreSQL doesn't use a lot of System V shared memory, so those limits won't apply. It uses POSIX shared memory.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong! I agree with @lmsurprenant, one of the Postgres devs says on that list:

PostgreSQL creates segments in /dev/shm for parallel queries (via
shm_open()), not for shared buffers.  The amount used is controlled by
work_mem.  Queries can use up to work_mem for each node you see in the
EXPLAIN plan, and for each process, so it can be quite a lot if you
have lots of parallel worker processes and/or lots of
tables/partitions being sorted or hashed in your query.